# How to export a class instance in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, umd

Im authoring a TS library, and would like to export an instance of a class, I intend for it be used as singleton in the consuming application.

Right now I have the following structure:

**index.ts**

```
export { Foo } from './my-class';
```

**foo.ts**

```
export class Foo {
  functionA() {}
}
```

I'm then building into UMD format using webpack and babel, and in another application (Angular), I am able to import in my class, instantiate it and use it accordingly.

```
import { Foo } from 'foo';

private foo = new Foo();

const x = foo.functionA();
```

Is there a way to return an instantiated instance of my class or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

So instead of having to do `new Foo()`, the imported Foo would actually already be an instance?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I should have mentioned, I am exporting other things such as interfaces, so I don't think a default class export would be the right way to go correct? - see [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can control what you're returning like so:

```
// Export the named class directly
export class Foo { }

// Export the named class indirectly
class Bar { }
export { Bar }

// Export an instance of the class directly
export const foo = new Foo();

// Export an instance of the class indirectly
const bar = new Bar();
export { bar };
```

Here's a [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Export%20the%20named%20class%20directly%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Foo%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Export%20the%20named%20class%20indirectly%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aexport%20%7B%20Bar%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Export%20an%20instance%20of%20the%20class%20directly%0D%0Aexport%20const%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Export%20an%20instance%20of%20the%20class%20indirectly%0D%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0D%0Aexport%20%7B%20bar%20%7D%3B) showing the code compiles and the produced javascript.

The TypeScript Handbook official documentation for exports (and imports, and re-exports): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export

The MDN documentation (courtesy of jo_va): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

And here's Basarat's guide for them: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html

Answer (score 18):

Yes this is totally possible, and this is a standard way to do it in TS too.

```
export default new Foo();
```

If however you want to import not only this instance but interfaces as well, you would export the singleton like this:

```
export const foo = new Foo();
```

You can find the `export` doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question since I don't think a default export is what I want as I am exporting other things too such as interfaces

Answer (score 7):

If you want singleton only, you should stick to the singleton convention,

```
  export class Foo {
    private static _instance = new Foo();
    private constructor() {

    }

    static get instance() {
      return this._instance;
    }

  }

  export const foo = Foo.instance;
```

Comment: Selected answer will work for singletons as well. Other languages principles doesn't necessarily fit in JavaScript.

Comment: I like this answer which demonstrate how to write a singleton in js. I had some issues when exporting instance (not singleton) and then `import` from multiple places causes the file to be executed multiple times (`console.log()` at top level in that file is run several times).

Comment: There's also a visual studio magazine post on how to write singleton using private constructor in detail: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/12/01/defining-classes.aspx

Comment: @ShaungCheng `import` should be cached after first import.  If a console.log was added to the accepted answer you would only see it once.  If you're seeing multiple console.logs that makes me think you are executing a factory function.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to export the instance of the class Members.

Export the class instance like this: `export const playerRoutes = new Routes`

Export the class like this: `export class player`